# Got stuck on a project stage

Tags: python, set

**I am currently stuck on a Jetbrains academy python code task, and it's the last stage of a section. Here is an overview of the task and contains what I need to achieve to pass this stage:**

The most recent version of the game is not so much fun, since we still don’t have a way to handle the player's victory. The player has 8 attempts to guess letters, and the number of remaining attempts decreases after each try even if the player guesses correctly.

In this next version, a player may get a lot of attempts because they are limited only by the number of mistakes they make. A player can be mistaken 8 times. They win when they have guessed all the letters and still have at least one try. If the player uses their last try and actually guesses the word, then they’ve won!

*Objectives:*

The player starts the game with 8 "lives", which is to say, our player can input a wrong letter 8 times.

1. Print That letter doesn't appear in the word and reduce the number of remaining attempts if
   the word selected by the program doesn't contain this letter.
2. Print No improvements and reduce the attempts count if the selected word contains this letter but the user has already tried guessing it.

Here is my code, and I believe my current code cannot display correct hangman letters within underscores according to the output console errors provided:

```
import random
words = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
word = random.choice(words)
list_letters = list()
print('H A N G M A N')
print()
print('-' * len(word))
pos = '-' * len(word)
attempts = 8
for _ in range(attempts):
    letter = input("Input a letter: ")
 
    if letter in word:
        i = 0 
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i] == letter:
                #1st error
                l = str(word[i])
                f = pos[word.find(letter)]
                r = pos.replace(f, l)
                print("Output errors, tried all possibilities:")
                print("1st error: " + pos)
                #2nd error
                print("2nd error: " + l)
                #3rd error
                print("3rd error: " + r)
                #4th error
                print("4th error: " + f)
                #5th error
                print("5th error: " + pos, l)
                #print(word.find(letter))
                #print(pos, replace[word.find(letter)])
                #print('-' * len(word), word.replace(masked, word[i]))
                #print(word.replace(masked, word[i]))
        if i == len(word):
            print(word)
            print("You guessed the word!")
            print("You survived!")
    elif letter not in word:
        list_letters.append(letter)
        attempts -= 1
        print("That letter doesn't appear in the word")
        print()
        print('-' * len(word))
    elif letter in set(list_letters):
        attempts -= 1
        print("No improvements")
    
    if attempts == 0:
        print("You lost!")
        break
    
    print()
 
print('''
Thanks for playing!
We'll see how well you did in the next stage
''')
 
#Output Console
---
 
H A N G M A N
 
----
Test Word: java
Input a letter: > a
Output errors, tried all possibilities:
1st error: ----
2nd error: a
3rd error: aaaa
4th error: -
5th error: ---- a
 
Input a letter: > j
Output errors, tried all possibilities:
1st error: ----
2nd error: j
3rd error: jjjj
4th error: -
5th error: ---- j
 
Input a letter: > a
Output errors, tried all possibilities:
1st error: ----
2nd error: a
3rd error: aaaa
4th error: -
5th error: ---- a
 
Input a letter: > v
Output errors, tried all possibilities:
1st error: ----
2nd error: v
3rd error: vvvv
4th error: -
5th error: ---- v
 
Input a letter: > a
Output errors, tried all possibilities:
1st error: ----
2nd error: a
3rd error: aaaa
4th error: -
5th error: ---- a
 
Input a letter: > a
Output errors, tried all possibilities:
1st error: ----
2nd error: a
3rd error: aaaa
4th error: -
5th error: ---- a
 
Input a letter: > a
Output errors, tried all possibilities:
1st error: ----
2nd error: a
3rd error: aaaa
4th error: -
5th error: ---- a
 
Input a letter: > a
Output errors, tried all possibilities:
1st error: ----
2nd error: a
3rd error: aaaa
4th error: -
5th error: ---- a
 
 
Thanks for playing!
We'll see how well you did in the next stage
```

I have tried all five possibilities to replicate the task's expected output but its just so close to be correct.

Here is the expected program output:

```
H A N G M A N

----
Input a letter: > j

j---
Input a letter: > i
That letter doesn't appear in the word

j---
Input a letter: > g
That letter doesn't appear in the word

j---
Input a letter: > g
That letter doesn't appear in the word

j---
Input a letter: > g
That letter doesn't appear in the word

j---
Input a letter: > g
That letter doesn't appear in the word

j---
Input a letter: > a

ja-a
Input a letter: > v

java
You guessed the word!
You survived!
```

It is greatly appreciated if anyone can help me resolve one small issue in my code, so that I won't need to spend gems to view solutions.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in range(attempts):
    ...
    elif letter not in word:
        attempts -= 1
```

is not doing what you think.
Python will evaluate `range(attempts)` and create an Iterable, then give it to the `for` loop which will thus run 8 times, assigning successively `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` to `_` which is named that way to indicate it is unused.
When you change (mutate) the `attemps` variable inside the loop, because `range(attemps)` was already evaluated, it will not affect the number of turns of the loop, it will just change the variable.

An example :

```
>>> for i in range(N):
        print(f"i={i} N={N}")
        if i > 2:
            print("i is greater than 2, setting N to 10")
            N = 10
# output :
i=0 N=5
i=1 N=5
i=2 N=5
i=3 N=5
i is greater than 2, setting N to 10
i=4 N=10
i is greater than 2, setting N to 10
```

What you want is to check at each turn of the loop if the game has finished, whether because the player found the word or because the player has no attemp left.

```
while (attempts > 0) and (pos != word):
```

would be better because you can't know how in advance many guesses the player will do, either good or already-known-to-be-bad letters.

Also, you check that the letter is not in the word before to check if it was already tried, so that inputing the same bad letter counts each time as a new bad guess. You should put the `elif letter in set(list_letters):` before the `elif letter not in word:`.

I recommend you use descriptive names for your variables : `f`, `l`, and `r` are not clear at all, it does not help when reading your code. Also, `pos` is not meaningful to me.

I do not understand at all what your `1st error` (and 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th) mean.

Here is a working solution :

```py
import random

print('H A N G M A N\n')

words = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
target_word = random.choice(words)
masked_word = "-" * len(target_word)
tried_letters = list()
remaining_attempts = 8

print("Chosen word:", target_word)  # debug

while (remaining_attempts > 0) and (masked_word != target_word):
    print("Remaining attempts:", remaining_attempts)
    print("Current progress:", masked_word)
    tried_letter = input("Input a letter: ")

    if tried_letter in tried_letters:
        remaining_attempts -= 1
        print("No improvements")

    elif tried_letter in target_word:
        tried_letters.append(tried_letter)
        masked_word = "".join("-" if (target_letter not in tried_letters)
                              else target_letter
                              for target_letter in target_word)
        print("Good guess !")

    elif tried_letter not in target_word:
        tried_letters.append(tried_letter)
        remaining_attempts -= 1
        print("That letter doesn't appear in the word")

    print()

if remaining_attempts == 0:
    print("You lost!")
elif target_word == masked_word:
    print(target_word)
    print("You guessed the word!")
    print("You survived!")


print('''
Thanks for playing!
We'll see how well you did in the next stage
''')
```

Feel free to adapta it to the exact requirements.